# Compare Dates with Springboot Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I try to compare two dates with format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` in a thymeleaf template.

I am able to compare a date, when I try:

```
 ${#dates.createNow().before(#dates.createNow())} // =false - just as an example
```

But my case is a bit tricky. At first I parse a string to obtain a date:

```
<th:block th:with="sdf = ${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss')}, isodate = ${isodate}, isodatemod = ${isodateModified}" >
```

Then I compare it:

```
<p th:switch="${#dates.format(sdf.parse(isodate)).before(#dates.format(sdf.parse(isodatemod)))}" />
```

This reveals the following error statement:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(sdf.parse(isodatemod)).before(#dates.format(sdf.parse(isodatemod)))
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method before(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type java.lang.String
```

I just don't see, why after parsing my date, it is still seen as string? Is there any way to make these two dates comparable in thymeleaf?

I use the following import:

```
implementation group:"org.springframework.boot", name:"spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
```

Comment: Wouldn't format turn the parsed date back into a string? Have you tried `<p th:switch="${sdf.parse(isodate).before(sdf.parse(isodatemod))}" />` ?

Comment: Ahhhh, that's it. Thank you, you saved my night!

Comment: Alternatively to the answer of @HopeyOne, you can add an extra attribute to the model and do the calculation in your controller.